# What is the best way to support Apple Music and Spotify in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, spotify, apple-musickit

I am looking to support Apple Music and Spotify in an iOS app (Swift specifically) and I was wondering what the best way to support would be?

Should I just use MusicKit and Spotify iOS SDK and then make models to support data from both?

If so, then how do I find Spotify iOS SDK instances for their structs? For example:

Apple's documentation for Albums shows all of it's instances:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickit/album

But Spotify's documentation for Albums doesn't show many instances:

https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/html/Protocols/SPTAppRemoteAlbum.html

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what your app will look like, I guess. Do you want to show Apple Music (AM) and Spotify content alongside each other? Or do you want to strictly separate them into different parts of the app?

For the former, I don’t see a way around creating common `struct`s for albums, artists, tracks, etc. That extra step would ensure your UI always got the same kind of structured object. You’d make the SDK calls, get your AM/Spotify-provided objects, and cast them into the `struct` you need for your app. You’d probably want to keep track if the `struct` originated from a AM or a Spotify object.

As to Spotify SDK: If that’s really the only documentation available (which, apparently, it is), you’d probably want to analyze the SDK yourself. What kind of data is returned from these URIs (e.g., JSON/XML data)? What do these `SPTAppRemoteAlbum` objects actually contain? Can you create intermediary objects for better handling?